# How to get thread # from a C++ AMP tiled index?

Tags: c++-amp

Basically, the only reason I'm using a tiled index is to get access to its barrier functions. The input data is 1 dimensional so I'm doing it like this:

```
parallel_for_each((BitM.extent / 2).tile<1>(), [=](tiled_index<1> TID) restrict(amp) {...
```

I need 1 thread per 2 units of input. Anyway, I think I can only get the tile # out of the tiled_index which in this case is always 0. The threads need their unique thread ID for the algorithm to run. Where can I get it from?

Comment: I think I found it, its under tiled_index.global[0]

Comment: That's correct. `tiled_index` allows you to access the global and tile indexes.